# Multiple tabs and accessibility

Tags: tabs, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag

If I want to use more than one tab-system in the same page, or even something more complex - two or more tab-systems one inside the other. How in cases like this I can ensure the user with AT for example, will understand which link belong to which tab-system.

For example:

`system01_link01; > system01_tab01;
system01_link02; > system01_tab02;
system01_link03; > system01_tab03;`

Inside of the `system01_tab02`, for example, we have another tab-system:

`system02_link01; > system02_tab01;
system02_link02; > system02_tab02;
system02_link03; > system02_tab03;`

I know how to mark properly this(or at least I think so :) ) - with `role="tablist"`, `role="tab"` etc, but is there anything I can use to mark specific relation between tab-links and tabs, so it will help the user in the more complex tab-systems?

Comment: `aria-labelledby` or `aria-owns` (though support is shaky on that one). Got a URL?

Comment: Please share your code in a more testable way, so we could say what our screen reader reads and how.